# vscode .devcontainer and docker-compose version mismatch

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I am trying to run a dev container on my vsode for ruby on rails, however, I cannot and getting the following error:

```
[2022-07-14T15:35:08.995Z] ERROR: Version mismatch: file /home/parham/projects/ruby/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml specifies version 2.4 but extension file /tmp/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1657812908036.yml uses version 1
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.136Z] Stop (1097 ms): Run: docker-compose --project-name ruby_devcontainer -f /home/parham/projects/ruby/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /tmp/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1657812908036.yml build
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.669Z] Error: Command failed: docker-compose --project-name ruby_devcontainer -f /home/parham/projects/ruby/.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml -f /tmp/docker-compose/docker-compose.devcontainer.build-1657812908036.yml build
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.669Z]     at Uu (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:204:419)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.669Z]     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.670Z]     at async kR (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:204:2335)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.670Z]     at async DR (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:188:2228)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.670Z]     at async QR (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:2177)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.670Z]     at async cb (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:3110)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.670Z]     at async i_ (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:13194)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.670Z]     at async n_ (/home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:245:12950)
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.682Z] Stop (6372 ms): Run in Host: /home/parham/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/node /home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --workspace-folder /home/parham/projects/ruby --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/parham/projects/ruby --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/parham/projects/ruby/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --remove-existing-container --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.684Z] Exit code 1
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.689Z] Command failed: /home/parham/.vscode-server/bin/92d25e35d9bf1a6b16f7d0758f25d48ace11e5b9/node /home/parham/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/dev-containers-cli-0.241.3/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --workspace-folder /home/parham/projects/ruby --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/home/parham/projects/ruby --log-level debug --log-format json --config /home/parham/projects/ruby/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --remove-existing-container --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true
[2022-07-14T15:35:09.689Z] Exit code 1
```

**UPDATE**

This is my `.devcotnainer.json` which forwards some ports and they are the only changes that I have added to the code.

```json
{
    "name": "Ruby on Rails & Postgres",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "app",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspace",
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "rebornix.Ruby"
            ]
        }
    },
    "forwardPorts": ["30000:3000", "54320:5432"],
    "remoteUser": "vscode",
    "features": {
        "git": "latest",
        "python": "latest"
    }
}
```

If you would like to reproduce select all additional features. That will cause error.

[image]

Comment: How to reproduce this? Any example?

Comment: I just used the vscode templates. Press F1 -> `Add Dev Container` -> `Ruby on Rails`. And then when everything is ready press F1 again -> `Rebuild and Reopen the Container`. This returns an error that I got above.

Comment: I don't see there is a option of `add dev container`, Could you share your `devcontainer.json` and the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @ikhvjs I have added an update. However, I retried it from scratch and it seems that it worked. I could not reporduce it but I put the errorneuos one above.